# Mustache - Check Boolean object property within object array

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

Actually I'm using [mustache-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache-express), and I know that I can use conditionals like: `{{^isFalse}}` and `{{#isTrue}}`, this stuff is working fine, but my problem is:

I send an object array to template and list their properties with {{prop1}}{{prop2}}

My object has a Boolean property that is only true for the first object, and I need to grab another property from this object and set as audio element source, which I couldn't do, [despite this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20386202/6585238). Probably I'm missing something... But this is what I tried with no success:

Access the Boolean property directly (as he did):

```
{{#myBoolean}}
<audio hidden src="{{myPath}}"></audio>
{{/myBoolean}}
```

Access within the array call, as I'm doing with my list:

```
{{#myArray}}
{{#myBoolean}}
<audio hidden src="{{myPath}}"></audio>
{{/myBoolean}}
{{/myArray}}
```

Is there any way I can do this without having to create a separate object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

```
{{#myArray.0}}
<audio hidden src="{{myPath}}"></audio>
{{/myArray.0}}
```